# showing background color for horizontal rule in html emails

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have the following code

```
<hr style="border:0; margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #F7D25F; height:1px;" />
```

However, this does not show up in the outlook 2003 client. How can I change it to show up?

Comment: Maybe if you change height 1px to 2px... I remember that IE6 had a similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<hr />` tag is poorly supported. Try to use a `<p>` one instead with the same parameters.

Comment: The problem here is that, at least in Outlook 2010, it forces the height to a minimum of 20px.  So you get this ugly, thick bar instead of a thin, elegant line.

Answer (score 4):

I tried that but it was still wonky in Outlook and Gmail as well. Instead, it works to use a border on a paragraph. Like this:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 6px; margin-top: 0px; border-top: 4px solid #000; text-align:center; font-size:1px;" >&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!  It worked in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a line break image like blow, but it doesn't show in Outlook.

```
<img src="images/line.gif" width="100%" height=1 >
```

Then I tried `td` as like below, which both work like a charm, including Outlook

```
<td style="margin: 0; height: 1px; background-color: #000; text-align: center;"></td>
```

or

```
<td style="border-top: 1px solid #000;"></td>
```

So yeah, I would definitely go with the `td` method